# Error 80 while restoring Firebird database using nbackup

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I took a `nbackup` and when i try to restore using the command :

```
  nbackup -R D:\test.fdb D:\test.nbk
```

It shows an error message:

```
Error(80) Creating database file D:\test.fdb via copying from D:\test.nbk
```

Comment: This should be in this section: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: However, from the first hit in google, there are open connections to your database, and this is causing the -R command to fail to overwrite. If there are no open connections to the DB, then your command should work

Comment: @zerohero No, with nbackup restore always fails if the database file already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error code 80 in the error message is a [Windows specific error code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx) for `ERROR_FILE_EXISTS`. You can only restore an nbackup backup to a new database file, it will fail when you attempt to overwrite an existing database.

As written in the documentation of NBackup, [Making and restoring backups](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/nbackup/firebird-nbackup.html#nbackup-backups):

> If the specified database file already exists, the restore fails and you get an error message.

In Firebird 2.5 and earlier the error does not include the reason, in Firebird 3 it will show:

> ```
> Error creating database file: D:\DATA\DB\FB3\FB3TESTDATABASE.FDB via copying from: fb3testdatabase.nbk
> -The file exists.
> ```

Comment: One can also check the error codes to get a clue what's wrong: https://blog.cincura.net/233250-understanding-some-firebirds-nbackup-error-messages-error-xxx-opening-database-file/ .

Comment: @cincura.net That will no longer work with Firebird 3 though ;)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for the info. Mistake was mine.. i was trying to restore it with an existing DB name. It worked now :)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Well, with Firebird 3 you'll get the message directly.